# limits and algebra

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm having trouble finding limits using just algebra... I can find it by graphing most of the time, but I get stuck otherwise. For example:

$$\lim_{t\to -1} \frac{t+1}{t^3-t}$$

My textbook gives the answer as 1/2 but I don't know how to get there using algebra. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we factor the numerator, we get $t(t+1)(t-1)$.

So then we have $\lim_{t\rightarrow -1} \dfrac{t+1}{t(t+1)(t-1)}$, and canceling, we get $\lim_{t\rightarrow -1} \dfrac{1}{t(t-1)}$. Then plugging in $-1$, we get $\dfrac{1}{(-1)(-2)} = \dfrac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty useful observation for you: $t^3 - t = t(t^2-t) = t(t-1)(t+1)$. This gives you

$$\lim_{t\to -1}\frac{t+1}{t^3-t} = \lim_{t\to-1} \frac{t+1}{t(t-1)(t+1)}.$$

Can you see how to proceed from here?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'm sure I will use this on other problems. :)

Comment: Definitely :) it's a useful trick.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{t+1}{t^3-t}=\frac{t+1}{(t^2-t)(t+1)}=\frac{1}{t^2-t}$$

Answer (score 0):

The answers so far are right, but no one really showed how to get the numerator, i.e. how t^3-t became t(t-1)(t+1)..... So I will explain:

Apply long division:

When t=1 this implies that t^3-t=0, so t-1 must be a factor of t^3-1. Therefore, we will divide t^3-t by t-1...

When you do this you will get t^2+t being another factor of t^3-t.

We also want to factorize t^2-t, when t=-1, t^2-t=o. Hence t+1 is a factor of t^2+1. We divide t^2+1 by t+1 and we get t.

We now have 3 factors of t^3-t, they are t,(t-1) and (t+1).